# what is $_SERVER['HTTP_DIGEST']

Tags: php, api, server, request

I got an error

> Undefined index HTTP_DIGEST

in this library https://github.com/conekta/conekta_prestashop/blob/master/notification.php#L23 (looks like it is some kind of callback/webhook function)
According to php manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php where is no HTTP_DIGEST

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_DIGEST'] = 'my-foo-string'` => Now there is... Maybe your lib is faulty or you use it wrong?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_DIGEST']` would hold a `Digest: ...` request header if the client sent one.

Comment: have sense, thank you @Cobra_Fast . I wonder why nothing in php manuals about such var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER` keys beginning with `HTTP_` mirror HTTP headers of the current request.

Mentioned in the [second most voted comment](https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#89567) in the documentation about `$_SERVER`.

Therefore, as @Cobra_Fast mentions in the comment, `$_SERVER['HTTP_DIGEST']` would contain contents of `Digest` HTTP header.